# No Animations in Unity Dock

Tags: cairo-dock, dock, animations

I've noticed that animations in the Unity dock are no longer showing.  I've installed the Paper Theme and Cairo dock (which I later removed).  I don't know what reports to run to help identify the problem.  If this questions isn't specific enough please let me know what additional information is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the result of the Paper theme.  Removing the theme restores the animations to the Unity dock.